# JavaScript: Type coercion ({}) + true = "[Object Obejct]true"

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, type-coercion

So i've been looking into type coercion and i get the basics, like how:

```
true + 0 = 1;
false + 0 = 0;
```

while messing around in the console I noticed that

```
({}) + true = "[Object Object]true";
{} + true = 1;
```

my question being why does `{}` get changed to `[Object Object]` when in `()`
and not when just added to `true` without the `()`?

Comment: Short version `({})` is an object, while your `{}` isn't.

Comment: ^ Specifically, `{}` is viewed as a block (like what you'd place your `for` loop code in) so really you're executing an empty block followed by `+true`.

Comment: ```{}``` in expression is a block hence like @mike-c said it's just empty block +true. In a statement like ```var a = {} + true``` the ```{}``` is an object and hence ```a``` will contain ```[Object Object]true```